# Installing a new font in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, tamil

I'm trying to install a new font for my emulator. Currently android doesn't support "Tamil" but rooted phones do have partial support with extra hic ups.

I wanna try and install a tamil font in my emulator. so I went to font directory under android sdk folder and replaced it with a Tamil unicode font latha.ttf

when I create a emulator for dat specfic version and runs it, I still see boxes instead of Tamil script??

wot am I missing?? can someone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanna try and install a tamil font in my emulator. so I went to font directory under android sdk folder and replaced it with a Tamil unicode font latha.ttf

The emulator has nothing to do with this directory.

> when I create a emulator for dat specfic version and runs it, I still see boxes instead of Tamil script??

Of course. You have not put the Tamil font in your emulator.

> wot am I missing??

If you find instructions for installing a Tamil font in a rooted phone, follow those instructions with your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever android fails to find a specific character it looks to DroidSansFallback.ttf, so what you need to do is replace the DroidSansFallback.ttf of the emulator by renaming a ttf font of your required language to DroidSansFallback.ttf.
Follow the steps as i described in [Bangla Font Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369552/how-to-install-bangla-on-android-emulator/10369560#10369560) or [Installing new font to android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator/10487991#10487991)