# Install Bengali fonts on Android emulator

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator

When I use Bengali characters in the emulator they are shown as boxes. How can I install the necessary font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever android fails to find a specific character it looks to DroidSansFallback.ttf, so what you need to do is replace the DroidSansFallback.ttf of the emulator by renaming a Bangla ttf font to DroidSansFallback.ttf. Do the following steps.

1.Get a market enabled rooted android emulator. You can find one here:
[Rooted Market Enabled AVD](http://www.ehalm.at/avd-2.2-market.php?l=en)

2.Then grab a explorer app, I prefer rootexplorer.

3.Rename a free Bangla ttf font to DroidSansFallback.ttf.

4.Create an AVD from the image you downloaded in step 1.

5.Push rootexplorer and DroidSansFallback.ttf to the sdcard of emulator via file explorer in DDMS (i'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE).

6.Install rootexplorer (you can use another explorer downloaded via market).

7.Open rootexplorer, click mount r/w.

8.Then goto sdcard and copy DroidSansFallback.ttf, then goto system, click mount r/w.

9.Then goto fonts and overwrite the existing DroidSansFallback.ttf.

10.Then give all permissions to the new DroidSansFallback.ttf from permissions option.

That's it, you can now use bangla anywhere in emulator but complex glyphs are not shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bangla on Android
Work on rooted Android 2.2 (Froyo).
Replace 2 skia files and add a custom font for getting system wide Bangla rendering support.

Details: http://androidbangladesh.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/bangla-on-android/