# Marathi Font Support for EditText in Android

Tags: android

i want to give input in a marathi language instead of english. i have done with setting TextView in Marathi. is it possible in android to give input in Marathi Language? if yes then please tell me how to do it in android. Thank you in advance.

Comment: tyr using typeface font ... and  inculde .ttf file in assert folder

Comment: thanks, i have successfully set Marathi Font to my TextView using .ttf file, now i want to give input in Marathi language through EditText.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAsset(), "urTTF.ttf");
final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);
textView.setTypeface(customF);
```

Comment: thank u. i have edited my question, now expecting some positive answer.

Comment: exactly, so how to do it.

Comment: u need to make custom keyboard and there u need to use the above solution, refer the link below , there may be others tuts also to make custom keyboard in android , just google it :http://www.winkeywong.com/2011/05/how-to-custom-keyboard-in-android.html

Comment: i have one doubt, is there is any way to type in hindi other than custome kayboard.

Answer (score 0):

download the marathi font and follow this link...hope this will will help you..
[Install Bengali fonts on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369552/install-bengali-fonts-on-android-emulator)